# Control Click in Robotframework-AutoItLibrary do nothing

Tags: python, windows, automation, robotframework, autoit

I have this script in AutoIt and it works just fine.
When coding in Robotframework, the same line is not working.
There is no error and the test pass the execution sucessfully but the click is not executed.

In AutoIt Script (OK):

```
ControlClick("Win Title","","[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]", "", 1, 255, 20)
```

In RF (NOK):

```
Control Click   Win Title    ${SPACE}    [CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]     ${SPACE}    1   255     20
```

I tried with ${EMPTY} and the behavior is the same.

If I remove the last parameters (1 255 20) it works but clicks on the wrong button (middle of the toolbar). With only the parameter 1 do not works.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `${SPACE}` should be `${EMPTY}`?

Comment: I tried with ${EMPTY} and the behavior is the same.
If I remove the last parameters (1   255     20) it works but clicks on the wrong button (middle of the toolbar). With only the parameter 1 do not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is missing one argument (button LEFT). This way it works:

```
Control Click  strTitle=Title  strText=  strControl=[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]    strButton=LEFT  nNumClicks=1  nX=255  nY=20
```

Comment: Seems correct. So you were setting `strButton` by using `${SPACE}`, rather than the default `strButton=LEFT` or another valid value. Since `LEFT` is a default value, you could probably omit `strButton=LEFT` and also `nNumClicks=1`. First 3 arguments of `Control Click` are required and after that you can use positional or named arguments like Python does. Well done.

Comment: @michael_heath I understand that but now I have a question. Can you help?
If I have the all required arguments why this works in AutoIt Script and not in RF?

#In autoit this works:

$val=ControlListView("Title", "","[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:2]","GetText",0,1)

#In RF I've got an empty result:

${val}=    Control List View   strTitle=Title  strText=    strControl=[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:2]    strCommand=GetText    strExtra1=0     strExtra2=1

Comment: @michael_heath strange. In my case PASS but with '[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:2]' or 'SysListView322' no value returned. Just empty. In auto it, it returns correctly.